# cocos2d JS WebGL rendering is not working in iOS 14 public beta

Tags: ios, webgl, wkwebview, cocos2d-js, ios14

I have some javascript games running on WKWebView with Cocos2d-x 3.17.2 and it has stopped being visible on devices with iOS 14 public beta. The clicks can be heard when touched but nothing is drawn on screen.

On further testing it was found that the games will draw when in canvas rendering mode but not in WebGL rendering mode. Has anyone else faced this issue or know why this happened in iOS 14 all of a sudden?

Update: The games running on phaser 3 with WebGL seems to working as expected on iOS 14.

Comment: It's called "beta" for a reason 

Comment: @gman Unfortunately this is a public beta. And players who updated can no longer play the game.

Comment: have you tried all the obvious things? Checked for WebGL errors? Run it in Safari instead of a WkWebView? Checked of other WebGL things run? Make the tiniest WebGL programs like one that just sets the clearColor and clears and if that works try drawing a single triangle? etc. etc. etc..? the obvious reason i happens is because it's beta. It sucks that some of your customers choose to upgrade but it warns right [in first paragraph of the beta program](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/faq) that stuff will break.

Comment: @gman No errors seen in console and the game does not render in safari either. Tried js games that run on top of other engines like phaser and they seem to work. Not sure if they are running on canvas or webgl. I will try out your other suggestions and update. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this on device in the latest beta (18A5342e)? I think it's fixed.

Comment: @JamesP This has been fixed in latest beta build.